# Remove Marker Google Map api v2 - Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, draw, marker, remove-if

I want to draw and remove Marker according to the previous conditions must be how

Example:

```
int a ;
if( a > 0 ) {
    draw Marker
}
if(a == 0) {
    remove Marker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
private Marker marker;

// ...

private void draw(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
            marker = null;
        }
    } else if (a > 0) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40,-4)));
    }
}
```